# Is it safe to remove wall framing around washer/dryer closet?

Tags: structural, door-frame, closet

We bought a 100+ year old shotgun style home (single level) about a year ago that has had several frankenstein like additions made to it which is pretty typical for the area we are in.

One of the additions is on the back of the house which we believe may have been a covered porch that they closed in and turned into a bathroom, laundry area, and narrow hall like room that has doors to the new back porch.

The issue we have right now is that we want to upgrade our washer/dryer to side by side units to better utilize the space, but the laundry room "closet" has a frame around it that is only 48" wide which makes it very hard to find good quality units that would fit.

The width of the interior of the closet is 57.5" though which would accommodate most washer/dryer sets so we are hoping to cut away the framing to allow us to use as close to the full interior width as possible.

There is no second level or attic / crawl space above this section of the house so it seems pretty safe but we're worried there could be a gotcha we haven't thought of.

I'm attaching some images of the framing but I can take more if I did not capture what I needed to.

[image: closet frame][image: closet frame with connecting rooms][image: close up frame]

Thanks for the help!

Comment: It's probably okay. Judging by the ceiling slope the wall behind the closet (or the exterior wall behind that wall) is load bearing. Once the trim and wall sheeting has been stripped, I would revisit that "probably okay" judgement. You'll need to see the underlying framing to form a defensible opinion.